# Can an sdp error cause stream corruption?

Tags: raspberry-pi, udp, streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I am trying to get a RTP (over udp) live stream (h264) from my Raspberry Pi using GStreamer (rpicamsrc). The video is being capture and forwarded to the browser using the Kurento Media Server, i.e. RPi -> KMS -> Browser.

The stream comes through with about 4s delay (which is not ideal but okay) however what is displayed seems to be corrupted and I am not sure why.

Corrupted Stream Display:

[image]

Some colleagues have suggested problems with interlacing/ p-frames (?) but I don't have any clue about this or what I should be looking for.

### Mangled SDP from receiver

```
String rtpSdpOffer =
    "v=0\r\n"
    + "o=- 0 0 IN IP4 " + senderIp + "\r\n"
    + "s=Kurento Tutorial - RTP Player\r\n"
    + "c=IN IP4 " + senderIp + "\r\n"
    + "t=0 0\r\n";

if (useAudio) {
  rtpSdpOffer +=
      "m=audio " + senderRtpPortA + " RTP/AVPF 96\r\n"
      + "a=rtpmap:96 opus/48000/2\r\n"
      + "a=sendonly\r\n"
      + sdpComediaAttr
      + "a=ssrc:" + senderSsrcA + " cname:" + senderCname + "\r\n";
}

rtpSdpOffer +=
    "m=video " + senderRtpPortV + " " + senderProtocol + " 103\r\n"
    + sdpCryptoAttr
    + "a=rtpmap:103 " + senderCodecV + "/90000\r\n"
    + "a=rtcp-fb:103 goog-remb\r\n"
    + "a=sendonly\r\n"
    + sdpComediaAttr
    + "a=ssrc:" + senderSsrcV + " cname:" + senderCname + "\r\n"
    + "";
```

### Gstreamer script to begin stream

```
    PEER_A={KMS_AUDIO_PORT} PEER_V={KMS_VIDEO_PORT} PEER_IP={KMS_PUBLIC_IP} \
SELF_PATH="{PATH_TO_VIDEO_FILE}" \
SELF_A=5006 SELF_ASSRC=445566 \
SELF_V=5004 SELF_VSSRC=112233 \
bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes,cname=(string)\"user\@example.com\"" \
    rpicamsrc ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=150,framerate=25/1 ! decodebin name=d \
    d. ! x264enc tune=zerolatency \
        ! rtph264pay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=(int)103,clock-rate=(int)90000,ssrc=(uint)$SELF_VSSRC" \
        ! r.send_rtp_sink_1 \
    r.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink host=$PEER_IP port=$PEER_V bind-port=$SELF_V \
    r.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host=$PEER_IP port=$((PEER_V+1)) bind-port=$((SELF_V+1)) sync=false async=false \
    udpsrc port=$((SELF_V+1)) ! tee name=t \
        t. ! queue ! r.recv_rtcp_sink_1 \
        t. ! queue ! fakesink dump=true async=false'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

SDP can cause corruption. If the codec data you would transmit in there does not match the stream. But it looks like you don't transmit codec data via SDP - but probably in-band.

The artifact in the image looks like a rowbyte/stride problem. Maybe caused by your video dimensions. It is recommend to use resolutions multiple of 16. However it should still work. It could be that the decoder/renderer does something weird. I would try to receive the stream and save to file watch it in a regular video player and check whether it displays better and what video dimensions are being reported.

Comment: I tried saving the file to .mp4 with: `gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=23938 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=testmedia.mp4`
Got error 0xc00d36c4 from windows 10 Movies&TV.
Also tried opening in VLC which said that it could not open the MRL